# StreamSocket crash on Windows 8.1 store app

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-store-apps

I have a server-client connection which works on both sides with `Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket`. On Windows 10, as Universal App, the connection is successful and data flows in back and forth without problems. On Windows 8.1, as a Windows Store app, the reading part of the StreamSocket fails at first attempt to read incoming data. The app closes and VS 2015 do not report any `Exception` nor the Output Window contains any useful information, other than `Program has exited with code 1`. Also, putting a breakpoint and then stepping through code doesn't work. Locals are not displayed and VS shows a message dialog:

> Unable to start debugging. The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

Here is the reading code:

```cs
public IAsyncAction Read()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            const uint length = 65536;
            string request = string.Empty;
            var socket = _signalingSocketService.GetSocket();
            var readBuf = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(length);
            var readOp = socket.InputStream.ReadAsync(readBuf, length, InputStreamOptions.Partial);
            readOp.Completed = (IAsyncOperationWithProgress<IBuffer, uint> asyncAction, AsyncStatus asyncStatus) =>
            {
                if(asyncStatus == AsyncStatus.Completed)
                {
                    var localBuffer = asyncAction.GetResults();
                    var dataReader = DataReader.FromBuffer(localBuffer);
                    request = dataReader.ReadString(dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
                    _signalingSocketService.HandoffSocket(socket);

                    List<string> requests;
                    var fileTask = BufferFileExists().AsTask();
                    fileTask.Wait();
                    if (fileTask.Result)
                    {
                        var bufferFileTask = GetBufferFile().AsTask();
                        bufferFileTask.Wait();
                        var bufferFile = bufferFileTask.Result;

                        var task = FileIO.AppendTextAsync(bufferFile, request).AsTask();
                        task.Wait();

                        var readLinesTask = FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(bufferFile).AsTask();
                        readLinesTask.Wait();
                        requests = (readLinesTask.Result).ToList();

                        var deleteTask = bufferFile.DeleteAsync().AsTask();
                        deleteTask.Wait();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        requests =
                            request.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
                    }
                } // if (asyncStatus == AsyncStatus.Completed)
            }; // readOp.Completed
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

What can cause such an odd behavior?